# Should I use copy elision or an rvalue reference to hand over a non-copyable type?

Tags: c++

I have a non-copyable but movable type `Handle`. I wanted to know if passing by value or passing by rvalue reference is preferred. Then I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58985085/movable-but-non-copyable-objects-passing-by-value-vs-by-rvalue-reference/58985176#58985176) that states:

> should the constructor exit by throwing an exception, the resource will be disposed of

---

As we can see the above suggests that there is at least one reason to prefer passing by value over passing by rvalue reference.

**My question is** is there a working example that demonstrates what the above quoted statement means. That is, I don't understand the meaning of the above quoted statement so an example might help me clarify that point.

For reference, below is the non-copyable but movable type:

```cpp
class Handle {
public:
    explicit Handle(/* ... */) {};
    Handle(Handle&&) = default;
    Handle(Handle&) = delete;

    Handle copy() { return Handle(/* ... */); };
};
```

Basically I wanted to know which of the following two `Container` definitions should be preferred.

1. Pass over the handle *by value* into the constructor, then move into a member.

   ```cpp
   class Container {
   public: 
       Container(Handle handle): mHandle(std::move(handle)) {}
       Handle mHandle;
   };
   ```
2. Pass over the handle *by rvalue reference* into the constructor, then move into a member.

   ```cpp
   class Container {
   public: 
       Container(Handle&& handle): mHandle(std::move(handle)) {}

       Handle mHandle;
   };
   ```

So how will the quoted statement look like in the form of a working example/code, when applied to this code snippet.

Comment: FWIW I just found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58985085/movable-but-non-copyable-objects-passing-by-value-vs-by-reference, but I do not understand the answer ...

Comment: Don't rely on optimizations like copy elision. Write code that behaves the same with or without optimization.

Comment: @user12002570 maybe I am mistaken, but isn't this "optimization" guaranteed since C++17? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

Comment: Yes, from C++17 there is "mandatory copy elision". [Movable but non-copyable objects: passing by value vs by rvalue reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58985085/movable-but-non-copyable-objects-passing-by-value-vs-by-rvalue-reference).

Comment: Exactly, and as the copy constructor is deleted, I do not "rely on optimizations", I enforce the compiler to do it or compilation will fail

Comment: Under what circumstances would a *move constructor* of `Handle` fail and have to `throw`?  Something to carefully consider.  (For my classes, all my move constructors have been `noexcept`.)

Comment: @Eljay true, this is the second point made in the referenced answer - and it does not apply in my case as the move constructor of `Handle` is noexcept

Comment: *Which of the following two Container definitions should be preferred.*  On my team, there is a great debate raging over which of these two styles we should use as a convention for our team's coding standard.  There is no clear cut answer, as far as I can tell.  I slightly prefer style #1.  Regardless of my slight preference, I think a codebase should adopt a convention and abide by it.

Comment: @Eljay another good point, my mental model so far did not include copy elision, so "a value would always be copied" so I preferred #2. Now I must say I also slightly prefer #1 as it leaves the copy semantics to `Handle` (the type decides whether it can be copied) and this also seems to be the preferred style in the codebase I work in. But I would still like to have "hard evidence" that this variant is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the case of another member besides the handle, whose member is constructed before moving the handle:

```cpp
class Container {
public: 
    Container(Other other, Handle handle) :
      mOther(other), mHandle(std::move(handle)) {}
    Other mOther;
    Handle mHandle;
};
```

If the constructor of `Other` throws an exception, whether the `Handle` **argument** has been moved from depends on whether `handle` is a reference - If the parameter is passed by value, it will always be moved from, if it is passed by rvalue reference, it will only be moved from if `Other` does not throw:

```cpp
{
  Handle handle;
  try {
    auto it = Container(other, std::move(handle));
  } catch(/* ... */) {
    // was handle moved?
    // With the rvalue reference variant, it could potentially still be in it's original state
    // With the value variant, it is always moved away (unless the move constructor throws)
  }
} // ~Handle() -> there is no observable difference after this point
```

In a lot of cases it should not matter, as either way the destructor of `Handle` should properly dispose the handle no matter whether it was moved away. Still, there might be cases where one either prefers to retain the Handle in case of an error before, in that case passing by rvalue reference makes sense or where one prefers that destruction of the not-moved handle is always done at the same place, in which case passing by value makes sense.

Comment: Okay, so in case I do, `Handle a; try { Container(file, std::move(a)); } catch(err) { … }` it will always be moved away with variant one whereas it might be moved away in variant two? What do I gain from that? Either way, the handle might be in an unspecified state afterwards

Comment: But thanks, I now at least understand the point of the other answer, I did not consider initializing another member that could potentially throw before moving into the mHandle member (as in my case it happens to be the first member)

Comment: Not every type is in an unspecified state after moving, and it might be important that the value be used or destroyed then.